# Can't run python app on digitalocean after adiing swagger

Tags: python-3.x, flask, digital-ocean, swagger-ui

I have added `flask_swagger_ui` in my app. In Pycharm everything works good.
After uploading this code on digitalocean i have problem. I've also installed flask-swagger-ui on server and in uwsgi log have this:

```
File "/var/www/html/control/app.py", line 9
    <<<<<<< HEAD
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

in app.py:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt import JWT

from security import authenticate, identity
from resources.user import UserRegister
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint      #this is line 9
```

Comment: Are you sure this `<<<<<<< HEAD` is not comming from git merge?

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot. the reason was there